# Case expressions in derived column for SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

How do I modify the column having 2,4,5 as values to 2=active, 4=closd, and 5=inactv in SSIS derived column? (SQL Server DB)

I'm expecting the column should show values.

'active' instead of '2'
'closd' instead of '4'
'inactv' instead of '5'

Comment: What have you tried? Its a fairly simple case expression which the docs should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
declare @a table( c varchar(100))
insert into @a
(c) values 
('2,4,5');
declare @equivalenttable table( id varchar(100),equivalent  varchar(100) )
insert into @equivalenttable
(id,equivalent) values 
('2' ,'active'),
('4' ,'closd'),
('5' ,'inactv');
```

*first* use `string_split` and `Cross apply`  for split string,
*second* use `join` with equivalent table  and
*third* use `string_agg`  as follows:

```
select 
  string_agg(equivalent, ',') within group (
    order by 
      id
  ) c 
from 
  (
    select 
      a1.value 
    from 
      @a CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c, ',') a1
  ) a2 
  join @equivalenttable e on a2.value = e.id
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PagXbARc)

Comment: Pretty sure OP just wants a straight forward replacement, not an aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16) (?:) as follows:

```
[inputcolumn] == "2" ? "active" : 
[inputcolumn] == "4" ? "closed" : 
[inputcolumn] == "5" ? "inactive" : 
""
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to stay away from derived columns and implement the case statement in the database query. Firstly it offloads the execution to the database. Secondly, derived columns are not that easy to work with and we want to keep the number of derived columns (or any number of ssis artifacts for that matter) as low as possible.